# Is it possible to define custom aggregates in InfluxDB?

Tags: influxdb

I'm currently using (abusing?) Postgres to store time-series data, and given the amount of data now being consumed I'm needing to migrate over to a true time-series database that supports continuous queries and retention policies. I'm looking at InfluxDB, and the only thing holding me back is the ability to define custom aggregates. I currently have a custom aggregate defined in Postgres that calculates a weighted average for data in a table based, with weights being determined by the value in one of the columns. For example, I have a `score` column with values between 1 and 9. When calculating the weighted average score, I multiply the score by 10 if it's between 4 and 6, and multiply it by 1,000 if it's between 7 and 9 before calculating the average.

Is it possible to do something similar in InfluxDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment InfluxDB doesn't allow for user defined functions within InfluxQL.

You could use both InfluxDB and [Kapacitor](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor) together to achieve what you're trying to do. Particularly you'd use the [User Defined Function Node](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v0.13/nodes/u_d_f_node/) in Kapacitor to define a weighted average UDF and then write the results of the UDF back into InfluxDB.

Comment: Is user defined function feature available in influx db now? It will of great help if somebody could help me with sample in influxdb, which are similar to stored procedures. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: Is is still not possible, however InfluxData has been working on a new query language that will allow for custom functions. See https://github.com/influxdata/ifql for more info.